# When creating a LiveUSB, write to the partition (/dev/sdb1) or to the device (/dev/sdb)?

Tags: live-usb, troubleshooting

How should I write the img or iso to a pen drive?

I'm trying several combinations, but fail to boot and I'm not sure the problem is in the writing to the pen drive, so I want to discard this possibility.

If I have a `nomadbsd-1.3.1.img` (for a persistent live-usb)

Should this work?

`dd bs=1M if=nomadbsd-1.3.1.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fsync`

or should it be `sdb1` instead?

Or, for example, with an ISO:

`cp debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-kde.iso /dev/sdb`

should above commend suffice?

Should the pen drive be prepared somehow before hand? It's new and was never used/formatted.

Comment: using dd is not recommended by Ubuntu as it has proven troublesome. It's also slow. How about using balenaEtcher?  https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: `dd` proven troublesome? Can you provide more info on that? I've been using it for ages for exactly the task the OP is doing without issues, should I be worried?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: I suppose the comment above yours has in mind using it on the wrong drive. That has surely proven troublesome. Hence he provided the link to a tool that avoids this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the `dd` on the whole disk. That's because the image already has all the stuff needed to boot.

So this should work (sdX is the device sda,sdb, or whatever):

```
dd bs=1M if=nomadbsd-1.3.1.img of=/dev/sdX conv=fsync
```

Note that that will erase the whole device though. You should check first you have the right one (I insert the drive and do a `dmesg`).